# String to Cassandra Timestamp

Tags: java, cassandra

I want to convert string date to Cassandra time stamp format

**Example date**
    String inputDate="20170525"

Comment: By java or cql ?

Comment: These are the default timestamp format  http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/timestamp_type_r.html#timestamp_type_r

Comment: Ashraful - From Java to cassandra using prepared statement

Comment: Do you really mean to store a date-only value in a date-time field (`timestamp`), or in a date-only field (`date`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You need to convert your string to `Date`**.
Java `Date` type maps cassandra `timestamp` type

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
Date date = dateFormat.parse("20170525");
```

Now you have the date you can insert or query with it in `prepared statement`

Note : You don't have any `timezone`. So default timezone will be used. If you want to specify the timezone use `dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone zone)` method

Comment: You are ignoring the crucial issue of time zone. You are creating a value representing the first moment of the day in UTC. This would be incorrect if the context of the date were meant for Montreal or Los Angeles etc.

Answer (score 0):

First, parse that input string as a `LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "20170525" , DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE ) ;
```

For a date-only value without time-of-day, you should be using type `Date` in Cassandra according to  [this documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cql_data_types_c.html).

You can exchange data as strings using standard ISO 8601 format. The java.time classes use the standard formats by default. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
String output = ld.toString() ;
```

> 2017-05-25

If you really want to store in the `timestamp`, you must specify a time-of-day. Perhaps you want the first moment of the day. Determining that specific moment on the timeline that requires a time zone. Do not assume the first moment occurs at `00:00:00`. Anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time mean the time may be another value such as `01:00:00`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ld.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

> zdt.toString(): 2017-05-25T00:00:00-04:00[America/Montreal]

Cassandra stores the `Timestamp` field only as UTC. So we need to adjust the `ZonedDateTime` from our desired time zone to UTC. The easiest way to do that is extract a `Instant`. The `Instant` class is always in UTC by definition.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
```

Generate a string in standard ISO 8601 format for Cassandra. Notice how the hour jumps from zero to four. Our time zone `America/Montreal` is four hours behind UTC on that date. So getting to UTC means adding four hours, 0 + 4 = 4.

```
String output = instant.toString() ;
```

> 2017-05-25T04:00:00Z

Going the other way when your retrieve this value.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2017-05-25T04:00:00Z" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).